Flutter app only runs from Terminal and does not print to Console After upgrade
I upgraded a flutter app to the latest SDK version 3.22 & installed a fresh Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1 and I have managed to eliminate all errors. 
If I run the app from Android Studio/VS Code (Using the run button), it only shows a black screen on launch
If I run the app from terminal i.e flutter run or flutter run --debug, the app runs well and shows appropriate screens but shows no debug errors so I'm unable to debug any further since I cant see any error or logs.
Here are the results of my flutter doctor command

Here is a simple print log that I would like to see when the login button is clicked. Note that I have used 3 different styles of printing to console and none of them seems to work.


Happens to me often in VS Code. One of these usually fix the issue ,

Terminate the build
Restart Dart Analysis Server
Restart IDE
Restart Computer

Still not sure what causes the issue but one of these fixes it.
